# Adding namespace in inner parent group in xslt v2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I tried all the codes I've seen in the internet with relevant requirement as I have. However, in my case, I also need to populate the namespace within the inner parent group. My XSLT didn't work as expected. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Section">
    <Section xmlns="www.hdgd.co">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Section>
</xsl:template>
```

**INPUT:**

```
<Record xmlns="www.hdgd.co">
<Data>
    <Section>
        <ID>1234DFD57</ID>
    </Section>
</Data>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
<Record>
<Data>
    <Section xmlns="www.hdgd.co">
        <ID>1234DFD57</ID>
    </Section>
</Data>
```

**GENERATED OUTPUT:**

```
<Record xmlns="www.hdgd.co">
<Data>
    <Section>
        <ID>1234DFD57</ID>
    </Section>
</Data>
```

Comment: what is your current output?

Comment: As the root element has `xmlns="www.hdgd.co"` there is no point and no way with XSLT to enforce the same declaration `xmlns="www.hdgd.co"` on a child or grandchild.

Comment: I edited my expected output. The <Record> should not have a namespace. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be unaware of namespaces inheritance. The default namespace declaration at the `Record` root element is applied to **all** elements of the input document. Therefore, in order to achieve the requested result, you must take all elements out of their namespace, while leaving the `Section` element and its descendants unprocessed:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="www.hdgd.co"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Section">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

If your input has attributes that need copying, then change the first template to:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thank you for you feedback. However, when I put an attribute in the Data element. It didn't copied the attribute when I tried to used the solution you've provided.

Comment: There are no attributes in your input example, so I did not handle them. See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds as if you want to remove the namespace from `Record` and `Data`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
  xpath-default-namespace="www.hdgd.co">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Record | Data">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRJM gives

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Record>
<Data>
    <Section xmlns="www.hdgd.co">
        <ID>1234DFD57</ID>
    </Section>
</Data>
</Record>
```